# Field showing $1 when rendered as HTML in Orchard 1.6

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

We have a field in our Content Type which is html. We want to put in a table of information in this field and display it on the screen when we go through to the Detail view.

When we do it, we find that every newline character in the field value is replaced with a $1 so we get something like the following

$1
$1
$1
$1 
etc.

In the code for the Fields.Common.Text.cshtml file, there is some code which calls ReplaceNewLinesWith("
$1")

Any idea why this is happening? We can work round it by putting the entire table html all on one line but we can't expect an end user to have to do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [post](https://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/19403) this was fixed and will be available on 1.7.

In the meanwhile what I did was remove the $1 from the following code at Fields.Common.Text.cshtml:

```
<p class="text-field"><span class="name">@name:</span> <span class="value">@(new MvcHtmlString(Html.Encode((HtmlString) Model.Value).ReplaceNewLinesWith("<br />$1")))</span></p>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, good to see it will be fixed. One thing though is that when we put in a table using <table> etc, it auto-formats the HTML into having newline chars at the end of each element. When this gets the ReplaceNewLinesWith("<br />") treatment, it ends up putting <br /> inside all the table tags which results in a about 20 <br />s in a row above the table as the non-expected elements are placed outside... is there a preferred way to allow a user to insert an HTML table?

Comment: New questions should be in a new question.

Comment: Graeme, I am facing the same problem as you.